# Unauthenticated SMTP now blocked due to conditional access

Tags: azure-active-directory, multi-factor-authentication

Overnight some of our unattended SMTP mailboxes (used for sending email from code) have stopped working with error:

```
Authentication requirement  Single-factor authentication
Status  Failure
Continuous access evaluation    No
Sign-in error code  53003
Failure reason  Access has been blocked by Conditional Access policies. The access policy does not allow token issuance.
```

I am trying to simply remove these accounts from the MFA requirement (which I dont actually recall switching on for all users) but every screen I click on I receive an error stating that I need a Premium subscription to configure conditional access. What am I missing? Surely an access policy that we are not licenced to configure should not be getting applied?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check if security defaults are disabled under
o365 Admin Center > Settings > Org Settings > Modern Authentication